# iTunes 12.5.5.5 can't go back/forward while in Music search -- Error Occurred, try again

Tags: itunes, macos

While in Music search/surfing through albums, songs and stuff sometimes you want to go back/forward (<kbd>cmd + [</kbd>/<kbd>cmd + ]</kbd>).

And I noticed today this problem:

[image]

```
Error Occurred, please try again later
```

So I just do in new search for my artist to find.  Movie and other stores are working fine.

In Console I got this:

```
default 21:53:40.156296 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 started
default 21:53:40.224167 +0200   iTunes  Setting identical now playing info, skipping update.
default 21:53:40.226106 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 event 1. err: 0
default 21:53:40.226163 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 complete. fd: 59, err: 0
default 21:53:40.226350 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 starting SSL negotiation
default 21:53:40.374577 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 SSL Handshake DONE
default 21:53:40.514791 +0200   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000058b6d0 canceled
```

Anyone got a clue?